# Error while using the Precision metric for MNIST digit classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, mnist

I am trying to achieve a high Precision score on the MNIST dataset using Tensorflow and Keras. My code is working if I set the metric to accuracy but when I set it to precision, it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (32, 10) and (32, 1) are incompatible
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

def bulid_model(n = 1, neuron=30,lr = 3e-3,input_shape=(784,)):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
    for layer in range(n):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(neuron, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = lr)
    model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer,metrics = [keras.metrics.Precision()])
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    (X_train,Y_train),(X_test,Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

    X_train /= 255
    X_test /= 255

    model = bulid_model(3,20,0.0156)

    history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=50)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precision, is a metric for binary classification. It computes `true_positives` and `false_positives` then simply divides `true_positives` by the sum of `true_positives` and `false_positives`.

[image: precision]

But `Accuracy` metric can be used for multi-class classification like MNIST, because it calculates how often predictions equal labels.

Comment: Actually, I am reading a book called "Hands on Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and Tensorflow. It has this question which tells us to experiment with the model to see if we can get above 98% precision

Comment: I think precision in this sentence is a general word for metric and he does not mean to use ``precision`` metric. ``Accuracy`` is also a metric which measures your model precision. Besides that you may be able to write your own precision function to fit in multi-class prediction, but I think it will be the ``accuracy`` which measures how many labels classified correctly.

Comment: Yes after some research, I feel that it means `accuracy`. Thank You.