# Value Error and dimensionality problem using the Iris Data Set with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, dimensions

I am attempting to practice classification with neural networks and just the old Iris Dataset imported from scikit-learn, but am running into a dimensionality problem I'm not sure how to solve.

I realize also that there are other ways, including tensorflow itself, to retrieve the iris data, that might already be in a better format to use the data, but just for the sake of understanding want to keep to using the data imported from scikit-learn.

```
# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

# get sequence length
T = X_train.shape[1]

X_train.shape

(100, 4)

i = Input(shape=(T,))
x = Dense(32, activation='swish')(i)
x = Dropout(0.40)(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='swish')(x)
x = Dropout(0.40)(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='swish')(x)
x = Dropout(0.40)(x)
x = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)

model_1 = Model(i, x)

# Compile the model
model_1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                 optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                 metrics=["accuracy", precision])

# Fit the model (to the normalized data)
r = model_1.fit(X_train,
                y_train,
                epochs=40,
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

The above code resulted in the following error message:

```
Epoch 1/40
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-262061005876> in <module>()
      8                 y_train,
      9                 epochs=40,
---> 10                 validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:792 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:457 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:73 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py:1366 update_state  **
        sample_weight=sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:623 update_confusion_matrix_variables
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

It's not clear how I should resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it two work, but not sure how or why this is.

I had also imported Precision

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Precision
precision = Precision()
```

and had originally passed that in the metrics along with `"accuracy"`. Removing that allowed it to run with just having:

```
# Compile the model
model_1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                 optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                 metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I'll have to figure out how to pass in additional metrics though, because I thought that should work

**EDIT**

The answer is [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087070/error-while-using-the-precision-metric-for-mnist-digit-classification). I was passing precision metric into a multiclass classification problem. Removing that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might have gotten some of your imports mixed up or had unexpected naming collisions when dealing with tensorflow and scikit-learn as there are over-lapping names if you dont use the full import path. This code below worked for me exactly. You may need to restart your kernel/notebook to clear all variables.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

# get sequence length
T = X_train.shape[1]

print(X_train.shape) # (100, 4)
print(X_test.shape)  # (50, 4)

i = keras.Input(shape=(T,))
x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='swish')(i)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.40)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='swish')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.40)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='swish')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.40)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)

model_1 = keras.Model(i, x)

# This helpful line prints out model information:
print(model_1.summary()) 

model_1.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                 optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                 metrics=["accuracy"])

# Fit the model (to the normalized data)
r = model_1.fit(X_train,
                y_train,
                epochs=40,
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: That is very odd. I am doing this in google colab, and just restarted the runtime, but still not working. Not sure what I am doing wrong that is causing this.

Comment: Did you copy my exact code, including all the imports and calling them the way I do? (e.g. `keras.Input()` not `Input()`) Still getting the same error?